# Using SQL Count function on a sub-query containing an EXCEPT clause

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL, and would appreciate some help.

This query returns a list of rooms that were not audited. However, I am unable to find the correct COUNT syntax so that I can return just the number of rows from the subquery. Any ideas?

```
SELECT "dba"."Room"."ID", "dba"."Room"."RoomNumName"

from "dba"."Room"

WHERE DeptID = 8225

EXCEPT

SELECT "dba"."vwResultInspection_iDashboards"."roomID", "dba"."vwResultInspection_iDashboards"."RoomNumName"
FROM "dba"."vwResultInspection_iDashboards" where

"dba"."vwResultInspection_iDashboards"."ClosedDate" > '2015-01-01'  AND "dba"."vwResultInspection_iDashboards"."ClosedDate" < '2015-01-31 23:59:59.000'


and DEPTID = 8225
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this mysql or sql server? It cannot be both.

Comment: does this work for you? if want only the count returned by except? `select count(1) from (<your except query>)x`

Comment: Having RoomNumName in both tables is probably bad.

Comment: Are you wanting to know the number of rows in the EXCEPT query or are you wanting to know the number of rows subtracted from the first query?

Comment: Hi Shawn,I wish to know the number of rows in the EXCEPT query. A little context may help: The first part of the query is simply getting a list of rooms with DeptID 8225. The EXCEPT part of the query is comparing that room list with any rooms that have matching IDs in the Results_Inspection table. It is the number of matching rooms that I wish to know.

Comment: BTW, apologies to all for my slow reply to your posts - I didn't expect such a rapid response!

Comment: @John So I think I already gave you an answer to the question. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not working because the columns returned by both select must have the same names, so please try this

```
SELECT "dba"."Room"."ID" ID, "dba"."Room"."RoomNumName" RoomNumName

from "dba"."Room"

WHERE DeptID = 8225

EXCEPT

SELECT "dba"."vwResultInspection_iDashboards"."roomID" ID, "dba"."vwResultInspection_iDashboards"."RoomNumName" RoomNumName
FROM "dba"."vwResultInspection_iDashboards" where

"dba"."vwResultInspection_iDashboards"."ClosedDate" > '2015-01-01'  AND "dba"."vwResultInspection_iDashboards"."ClosedDate" < '2015-01-31 23:59:59.000'


and DEPTID = 8225
```

Answer (score 0):

No reason to use `EXCEPT` which compares entire rows. This is the right way to do the query. If `roomID` can be null then you'll need to add `AND d.roomID IS NOT NULL` in the subquery.

```
SELECT r.ID, r.RoomNumName
FROM dba.Room AS r
WHERE
        DeptID = 8225
    AND r.ID NOT IN (
        SELECT d.roomID
        FROM dba.vwResultInspection_iDashboards as d
        WHERE
                DEPTID = 8225
            AND d.ClosedDate > '2015-01-01' AND d.ClosedDate < '2015-02-01'
    )
```

The row count of the second query is just this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM dba.vwResultInspection_iDashboards AS d
WHERE
        d.DEPTID = 8225
    AND d.ClosedDate > '2015-01-01' AND d.ClosedDate < '2015-02-01'
```

The number of rows actually excluded is different:

```
SELECT
    /* not sure if join is 1:M so using distinct */
    count(case distinct d.roomID) as Excluded
FROM dba.Room AS r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dba.vwResultInspection_iDashboards as d
        ON      d.roomID = r.ID AND d.DeptID = r.DeptID
            AND d.ClosedDate > '2015-01-01' AND d.ClosedDate < '2015-02-01'
WHERE r.DeptID = 8225
```

or this:

```
SELECT
    count((
        /* dummy aggregate to flatten multiple rows since not sure about 1:M */
        SELECT count(d.roomID)
        FROM dba.vwResultInspection_iDashboards as d
        WHERE d.DEPTID = 8225 and d.roomID = r.ID /* correlated */
            AND d.ClosedDate > '2015-01-01' AND d.ClosedDate < '2015-02-01'
    )) as Excluded
FROM dba.Room AS r
WHERE r.DeptID = 8225
```

Comment: Except I don't see how your query will return a count.

Comment: Yes, I guess I lost the question in the middle of the confusion about the query.